# How can I separate the df from a list

Tags: r

I have a list of df lst1. I would like to generate an excel file for each subject ID and each file will contain mutiple sheets, which equal to the df in lst. And at the end, I would like to add label on top the col names from dfs in lst.

```
lst<-list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), BRTHDTC = c("1953-07-07", 
"1963-07-02", "1940-09-11", "1955-12-31", "1950-12-04"), SEX = c("Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), DSDT = c("2016-03-14", 
"2017-04-04", NA, "2016-05-02", "2018-07-06"), DSDT_P = c(NA, 
NA, "UN-UNK-2015", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Visits = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), Visit = c("Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1"
), VISND = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

Label<-structure(list(Var = c("SubjectID", "BRTHDTC", "SEX", "DSDT", 
"DSDT_P", "Visit", "VISND"), label = c("Subject ID", "Birthday", 
"Gender", "DS Date", "DS Date Prob", "Date of Visit", "ND Visit"
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

IDlist = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201")
```

The outcome should looks like sth as

```
out
$Demographics
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 Subject ID Birthday   Gender
2 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female


$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P      
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       
1 Subject ID DS Date    DS Date Prob
2 101-01-101 2016-03-14 <NA>        
       

$Visits
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND   
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>   
1 Subject ID Date of Visit                ND Visit
2 101-01-101 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>
```

The code I have so is :

```
Indivadual_xlsx<-function(Subject_id){
lst %>% map(~ {nm1 <- deframe(Label)[names(.x)];  filter(., SubjectID == Subject_id) %>% 
    bind_rows(as.list(setNames(names(nm1), nm1)), setNames(., nm1))  })%>%
     write.xlsx(paste0(Subject_id, ".xlsx"))
}
IDlist %>% map(Indivadual_xlsx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `transpose` after doing the `match` with `deframe`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
lst1 <- map(lst, ~ .x %>%
              split(.$SubjectID) %>%
               map(~ bind_rows(as.list(deframe(Label)[names(.x)]), .x) )) %>% 
       transpose
```

-checking

Output of first `list` element

```
lst1[[1]]
$Demographics
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 Subject ID Birthday   Gender
2 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female

$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P      
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       
1 Subject ID DS Date    DS Date Prob
2 101-01-101 2016-03-14 <NA>   

$Visits
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND   
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>   
1 Subject ID Date of Visit                ND Visit
2 101-01-101 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>
```

Then, we use `write.xlsx` on the `list` elements by looping over the `list`

```
library(openxlsx)
imap(lst1, ~ write.xlsx(.x, file.path("C:/document",
                sprintf("subject_%s.xlsx", .y))))
```

There excel file names will be that of the elements of 'IDlist' and the sheet names will be the names of the inner list elements i.e 'Demographics', 'DiseaseStatus', and 'Visits'

Comment: It sounds like a good idea. one question, Why we need transpose?

Comment: @Stataq the reason is that when we do a `split` inside, the inner list will be by 'SubjectID' or 'IDlist'. I want that to be outer as in your expected.  So, that each excel file will be one SubjectID

Comment: @Stataq please let me how it is working on your data

Comment: If I run it with transpose, i got error codes `Error in transpose(.) : Item 1 of list input is not an atomic vector`

Comment: @Stataq Are you using the `purrr::transpose` with the same example data as I don't get any errors in the example showed

Comment: Is it on the same example data you showed here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232836/discussion-between-stataq-and-akrun).